# How to sync settings of Chitubox between computers?

Tags: chitubox

I tuned my print settings pretty good. Prints no longer fail, details are as good as it gets, all nice and dandy.

Problem is, I did it on my laptop. And it lacks both RAM and brute CPU force for big, detailed models. I don't want to go over it all by hand because, knowing my luck, I would miss something. So, how can I transfer ALL setting? Support contact sizes, resin profiles, all that? And better yet, how can I keep them in sync?